# How to extract binlog related to a single table in MySQL from binlog file?

Tags: mysql-5.7, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I am using MySQL 5.7.31 and binlogs enabled in MIXED format.

I am trying to perform a partial PIT Recovery, i.e. restoring  specific table in a specific instant of the past. After restoring my last partial backup, of the table I need to take back in time, I am looking for a way to apply the binlogs related to it, up  to my desired point in time.

Is there a way, by mean of any command e.g. "sed", to extract the binlog of a single table from a binlog file, in order to perform the single table Point-in-time Recovery?

I did something similar for the restore of the single table. My doubts come from the form the binlogs are written and I haven't a clear idea on what poprtion to isolate and how to actually perform it, to achieve my goal above explained.

Comment: why nit simpoly restore the database till day x and take the restored table, filtering all sql files coulb be possibles, but figuring all awk ort sed comands, with testing, could cost more time that ti restore the thing